Check if this code uses a data sliding window
I want help to check if the following code (from https://github.com/jsh4887/ConvLSTM/blob/main/1.%20Make_dataset.py):
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pickle
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler


def createFolder(directory):
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)
    except OSError:
        print('Error: Creating directory. ' + directory)


def Make_Dataset_df(path, start_year, end_year, start_lon, end_lon, lon_bin, start_lat, end_lat, lat_bin):
    dif_year = (end_year - start_year) + 1
    total_year = np.linspace(start_year, end_year, dif_year, dtype=int)

    real_df = pd.DataFrame()

    path = path

    for y in range(len(total_year)):

        data_path = path + str(total_year[y]) + '/'
        file_list = os.listdir(data_path)
        file_list.sort()

        Error_msg = data_path + '.DS_Store'

        if os.path.exists(Error_msg):
            os.remove(Error_msg)

            data_path = path + str(total_year[y]) + '/'
            file_list = os.listdir(data_path)
            file_list.sort()

        else:
            print("Can not delete the file as it doesn't exists")

        for O_f in range(len(file_list)):

            DCGAN_file = data_path + file_list[O_f] + '/completed_pb_lr/1950.txt'

            if os.path.exists(DCGAN_file):

                # DCGAN-PB result
                with open(DCGAN_file, "r") as file:
                    DCGAN_pb_value = np.array([float(i) for line in file for i in line.split('/n') if i.strip()])

                # DCGAN_PB_result = np.reshape(DCGAN_pb_list, (32, 32))
                obs_year = int(file_list[O_f][16:20])
                obs_month = int(file_list[O_f][21:23])
                obs_day = int(file_list[O_f][24:26])
                obs_hour = int(file_list[O_f][27:29])

                # spec_time = datetime(obs_year, obs_month, obs_day, obs_hour, 0, 0)

                nan_value = np.where((DCGAN_pb_value == 9999.0) | (DCGAN_pb_value < 0.5) | (DCGAN_pb_value > 100))

                if len(nan_value[0]) == 0:
                    DCGAN_pb_value = DCGAN_pb_value
                else:
                    DCGAN_pb_value[nan_value] = np.nan

                date_data = {'Year': int(obs_year),
                             'Month': int(obs_month),
                             'Day': int(obs_day),
                             'Hour': int(obs_hour)}

                df_1_date = pd.DataFrame(date_data, index=[0])
                df_1_TEC = (pd.DataFrame(DCGAN_pb_value)).transpose()
                df_comb = pd.concat([df_1_date, df_1_TEC], axis=1)

                real_df = pd.concat([real_df, df_comb], axis=0)

            else:

                print('There is no data')

    return real_df


################### Setting ###################

start_year = 2010
end_year = 2010
start_lat = 25.5
end_lat = 41
start_lon = 120
end_lon = 135.5
lat_bin = 0.5
lon_bin = 0.5

path = '/Users/jeongseheon/Desktop/JSH/[2] Data/DCGAN_result/'
saving_path = '/Users/jeongseheon/Desktop/JSH/[1] Project/Forecast_TEC_convLSTM/Dataset/'
# createFolder(saving_path+'initial_dataset_2d')
title_name = 'DCGAN_PB_TEC_' + str(start_year) + '_' + str(end_year) + ''

if os.path.exists(saving_path + 'initial_dataset_2d/' + title_name + '_Dataset_'+str(start_year)+'_'
                  +str(end_year)+'.csv'):

    df_values = pd.read_csv(saving_path + 'initial_dataset_2d/' + title_name + '_Dataset_'+str(start_year)+'_'
                  +str(end_year)+'.csv')
    date = df_values.values[:, 1:5]
    values = df_values.values[:, 5:]

else:

    df_data = Make_Dataset_df(path, start_year, end_year, start_lon, end_lon, lon_bin, start_lat, end_lat, lat_bin)
    df_data_intp = df_data.interpolate()
    date = df_data_intp.values[:, 0:4]
    values = df_data_intp.values[:, 4:]

    # interpolation을 했음에도 불구하고 첫 값이 NAN인 경우 interpolation을 하지 못함 따라서 0으로 변경
    nan_value = np.where(np.isnan(values) == True)
    values[nan_value] = 0

    df_date = pd.DataFrame(date)
    df_values = pd.DataFrame(values)

    save_df = pd.concat([df_date, df_values], axis=1)

    save_df.to_csv(saving_path + 'initial_dataset_2d/' + title_name + '_Dataset_'+str(start_year)+'_'
                  +str(end_year)+'.csv')


def generate_dataset(data, date, n_samples, past_history, future_target):
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(data)
    data_4d = scaled_data.reshape(n_samples, 32, 32, 1)

    date_data_n_frames = []
    for i in range(n_samples - past_history - future_target - future_target):  # 영화 샘플수만큼 반복

        for t in range(past_history):

            hist_data = data_4d[i + t, :, :, :]  # 32 * 32 * 1
            hist_data_n_frames_1 = hist_data.reshape(1, 32, 32, 1)
            date_data_n_frames_1 = date[i + (t + future_target), :]

            if t > 0:
                hist_data_n_frames = np.concatenate([hist_data_n_frames, hist_data_n_frames_1])
                date_data_n_frames = np.concatenate([date_data_n_frames, date_data_n_frames_1])
            else:
                hist_data_n_frames = hist_data_n_frames_1
                date_data_n_frames = date_data_n_frames_1

        for f in range(future_target):

            next_data = data_4d[i + (f + future_target), :, :, :]  # 32 * 32 * 1
            next_data_n_frames_1 = next_data.reshape(1, 32, 32, 1)

            if f > 0:
                next_data_n_frames = np.concatenate([next_data_n_frames, next_data_n_frames_1])
            else:
                next_data_n_frames = next_data_n_frames_1

        hist_data_5d_1 = hist_data_n_frames.reshape(1, -1, 32, 32, 1)
        next_data_5d_1 = next_data_n_frames.reshape(1, -1, 32, 32, 1)
        date_data_1 = date_data_n_frames.reshape(1, -1)

        if i > 0:
            hist_data_5d = np.concatenate([hist_data_5d, hist_data_5d_1])
            next_data_5d = np.concatenate([next_data_5d, next_data_5d_1])
            date_data_5d = np.concatenate([date_data_5d, date_data_1])
        else:
            hist_data_5d = hist_data_5d_1
            next_data_5d = next_data_5d_1
            date_data_5d = date_data_1

        print('Data shape:' + str(hist_data_5d.shape))
        print('Future shape:' + str(next_data_5d.shape))

    return hist_data_5d, next_data_5d, date_data_5d, scaler


past_history = 24
future_target = 24

hist_data_5d, next_data_5d, date_data_5d, scaler = generate_dataset(values, date,\
                                                                    values.shape[0], past_history, future_target)

createFolder(saving_path + 'model_input_dataset_5d')
with open(saving_path + 'model_input_dataset_5d/' + title_name + '_past_' + str(past_history) + '_Dataset_'
          +str(start_year)+'_'+str(end_year)+'.pickle', 'wb') as t1:
    pickle.dump([hist_data_5d, next_data_5d, date_data_5d, scaler], t1)

uses a sliding window with stride smaller than 24 frames in each iteration, in relation to the frames used in each record of the final array given by using the hist_data_5d, next_data_5d, date_data_5d, scaler = generate_dataset(values, date, values.shape[0], past_history, future_target) code, and what would be the value of stride. I think the stride is 24 frames, but I'm very confused about reading the code.

Yes it’s using sliding windows in this sense. If you look the function generate_dataset,

it iterates over each sample in the dataset n_samples, minus the past and future target frames to ensure there's enough data for historical and future frames.

Within each iteration, it iterates over the past_history frames to collect historical data hist_data and their corresponding dates date_data. These frames are concatenated together to form a sequence of historical frames hist_data_n_frames and dates date_data_n_frames.

It also iterates over the future_target frames to collect future data next_data. These frames are concatenated together to form a sequence of future frames next_data_n_frames.


The sliding window is the nested loops over past_history and future_target, which shift the window by one frame at each iteration to create overlapping sequences.
Usually if you see a for loop and index slicing, you have a moving window. This is my rule of thumb but others might disagree.
Hope this helps!
I will add the part of the code which you asked for.
for i in range(n_samples - past_history - future_target - future_target):

    for t in range(past_history):

        # Collect historical data

    for f in range(future_target):

        # Collect future data

all of these increment by 1
Because the loops increment by 1 at each iteration (range(x) defaults to starting at 0 and incrementing by 1 until it reaches x - 1), the stride between each frame in the sequence is 1.

anarchy, thank you very much. Can you please point me to where in the code what you said here ("The sliding window is the nested loops over past_history and future_target, which shift the window by one frame at each iteration to create overlapping sequences.") occurs? This is the most crucial point for me.

I ended up not formulating my question more clearly, but my main question about the existence of the sliding window is whether there is a "stride" smaller than 24 frames passed in each iteration, from what you said it seems that there is a smaller stride, specifically 1 frame, would that be it?

I just edited my question to make it clearer.

I think the stride is just 1? It moves one pixel at a time only.

Ok, but can you point me it in the code, please?
